# Websocket connection being closed on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a set of apps deployed in Docker containers that use websockets to communicate. One is the backend and one is the frontend.

I have both VM instances inside instance groups and served up through load balancers so that I can host them at https domains.

The problem I'm having is that in Google Compute Engine, the websocket connection is being closed after 30 seconds.

When running locally, the websockets do not time out. I've searched the issue and found these possible reasons, but I can't find a solution:

1. Websockets might time out on their own if you don't pass "keep alive" messages to keep them active. So I pass a keep alive from the frontend to the backend, and have the backend respond to the frontend, every 10 seconds.
2. According to the [GCE websocket support docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#websocket_proxy_support), some type of "upgrade" handshake needs to occur between the backend and the frontend for the websocket connection to be kept alive. But [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism), "if you're opening a new connection using the WebSocket API, or any library that does WebSockets, most or all of this is done for you." I am using that API, and indeed when I inspect the headers, I see those fields:

[image: websocket connection headers]

3. The [GCE background service timeout docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#session_affinity) say:

> For external HTTP(S) load balancers and internal HTTP(S) load
> balancers, if the HTTP connection is upgraded to a WebSocket, the
> backend service timeout defines the maximum amount of time that a
> WebSocket can be open, whether idle or not.

This seems to be in conflict with the [GCE websocket support docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#websocket_proxy_support) that say:

> When the load balancer recognizes a WebSocket Upgrade request from an
> HTTP(S) client followed by a successful Upgrade response from the
> backend instance, the load balancer proxies bidirectional traffic for
> the duration of the current connection.

Which is it? I want to keep sockets open once they're established, but requests to initialize websocket connections should still time out if they take longer than 30 seconds. And I don't want to allow other standard REST calls to block forever, either.

What should I do? Do I have to set the timeout on the backend service to forever, and deal with the fact that other non-websocket REST calls may be susceptible to never timing out? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Increasing the timeout on the backend service fixed the issue with the websockets closing. But I would still like to find a solution that lets me do this for websockets ONLY, rather than all http requests. I would also like it to not timeout at all, rather than having to enter a very large amount of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this GCP doc](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#websocket_support) "When the load balancer recognizes a WebSocket Upgrade request from an HTTP(S) client followed by a successful Upgrade response from the backend instance, the load balancer proxies bidirectional traffic for the duration of the current connection. If the backend instance does not return a successful Upgrade response, the load balancer closes the connection."

In addition, the websocket timeout is a combination of the LB timeout and the bakckend time out. I understand that you already have modified the backend timeout. so you can also adjust the load balancer timeout according to your needs, pleas keep in mind that the default value is 30 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

We have a similar, strange issue from GCP but this is without even using a load balancer. We have a WSS server, we can connect to it fine, it randomly stops the feed, no disconnect message, just stops sending WSS feeds to the client. It could be after 2-3 minutes it could be after 15-20 minutes but usually never makes it longer than that before dropping the connection.

We take the exact same code, the exact same build,(its all containerized) and we drop it on AWS and the problem with WSS magically disappears.

There is no question this issue is GCP related.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30087258)